# android custom list view position and click event issue(list getting dynamic data from server)

Tags: android

I need a help more.Actually i am facing a problem for my listview that is getting new data after each 3 seconds as i asked you was working fine now.but there is a problem when i click on the listrow (launch the new activity show the visitordetail page) i am passing some data from listview row to another activity.my problem is that listview is getting new data  after each 3 seconds when  i click the listrow then next activity started and show the visitordetail page in the case update method is called before clicking the listview row but if i click the row and same time new data is received and added to row that app is crashed.

what should i do that my app is not crashed and work fine when click on row or row's button.i passing sessiontext and iptext related to that row to next activity.

my class code is following the link given below.
http://www.coderanch.com/t/568877/Android/Mobile/android-custom-list-view-position#2585198
eranch.com/t/568803/Android/Mobile/start-new-activity-when-click

one thing i more want with  my app  when i click on listiview row update list method is stopped and new activity is started and when i come back by from new activity the update method is again started how can this possible?

when i am coming back to next activty my logcat is like the following.............

```
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.live2support/com.live2support.L2STest}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was cancelled
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was cancelled
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:566)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:485)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at com.live2support.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:157)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at com.live2support.BaseActivity.onRestart(BaseActivity.java:932)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestart(Instrumentation.java:1139)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:3805)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performRestartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:160)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchResume(LocalActivityManager.java:518)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.ActivityGroup.onResume(ActivityGroup.java:58)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
02-29 12:53:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(5066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
```

when i am click listrow app is crashing in that case new data update call is started and i purged the timer and code of my event like this crashing my app sometime.........

convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

```
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        timer.purge();
                        if(SessionText.get(position)!=null&&IPText.get(position)!=null){
                        Intent i=new Intent(BaseActivity.this,VisitorDetail.class);
                        i.putExtra("ID", id);
                        i.putExtra("Position",position);
                        i.putExtra("From", from);
                        i.putExtra("SessionText", SessionText.get(position));
                        i.putExtra("IPTEXT",IPText.get(position));
                        startActivity(i);

                        }

                        else{

                            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                                public void run() {
                                    TimerMethod();
                                }

                            }, 0, 3000); 
                        }



                    }});
```

anyone can help me to solved out the issue.....................

Comment: Finally i got solved my problem...........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cancel timer onItemClick, so it wont update data when you have clicked on a item, and if it is needed after item click, start timer again, after call startActivity.

Comment: i try whatever u said but one thing i want when i click on listiview row update list method is stopped and new activity is started and when i come back by from new activity the update method is again started how can this possible?

Comment: when i clicked the listview row new activity started but when i come back to new activity using back button app is crashing.

Comment: ok, in onResume() mehtod create timer again and start the timer.

Comment: until now i am getting the same problem app is crashing when i am coming back to next activty..........

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a java synchronized block

Comment: how can i use java synchronized block can you refer me an example?